# Import directories into Subversion repository

Tags: windows, svn

I put some legacy source code to Subversion repository. Each version of the code is in a directory where the directory name is the version of that version. I can add each file to the Subversion and commit after adding all files:

```
mkdir workingCopy
svnadmin create repo
svn checkout file "///%CD%\repo" workingCopy
svn propset svn:ignore "*.obj" workingCopy
xcopy directory1\* workingCopy
cd workingCopy 
svn add file1
svn add file2
...
cd ..
svn commit -m "version1" workingCopy

rem to by continue with directory2..directoryN
```

But this is cumbersome and should be possible with `svn import`. I failed to find the correct parameters to get all files:

```
rem all these commands fail
svn import -m "version_dir1" directory1 workingCopy
svn import -m "version_dir1" directory1 file:///workingCopy
svn import -m "version_dir1" directory1 file:///%CD%\workingCopy
cd workingCopy
svn import -m "version_dir" ..\direcotory1
```

How can I import entire directory trees as Subversion revision?

Answer (score 0):

Read **carefully** description of [`svn import`](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html) command

1. You import directly into repository, generating new commit for each import
2. WC (of empty before 1-st import) is useless and will add *zero-value* at this stage
3. You *may want* to have default layout (at least partially) `trunk/branches/tags` in your repo and have|must to remember that `svnadmin create` *will not build* any additional nodes in created repo

On the assumption that:

- `%CD%\repo` is repo-path on local FS
- `/FULL/PATH/TO/directory1` ... `/FULL/PATH/TO/directoryN` are paths to enumerated versions of code

you can use smth. like

`svn import /FULL/PATH/TO/directoryX -m "Version X" file:///%CD%\repo/trunk`

for each source-directory in the right (historical) order

Comment: It looks like my problem was spaces in %CD%. In a plain path w/o spaces I was able to import one directory. But the next tries fail. Corresponding to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214184/multiple-import-into-svn-repository/2214459#2214459 the idea to `svn import` several version will not work. I will have to copy and commit the files from other directories. So my question was a bit misleading. Do you agree?

Answer (score 0):

The actual full paths to the directory as well as to the repository must not include blank characters. Or the path must be surrounded by quotation marks.

The `svn import` command is used to import an unversioned tree into the repository. It is only possible to import the first revision from a directory tree. Svn `import` checks that the files are new in the repository. Subsequent imports of the same files are not supported. These versions must be added with a series of `svn commit` commands.